# Efficient swap method for a derived class

Tags: c++

Here is a code fragment that speaks for itself. Thank you!

```
class Foo : private std::vector<int>
{
public:
    void swap(Foo& x)
    {
        std::swap(bar, x.bar);
        // what goes here?
    }
private:
    int bar;
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
std::vector<int>::swap(x);
```

<strike>But, you shouldn't inherit from vector.</strike>

Due to [injected-class-names](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1994/N0444.pdf), this can be rewritten as

```
vector::swap(x);
```

Comment: There's no problem with inheriting from `vector` privately.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see the "private".

Comment: Anyway, there are generally better design techniques than private inheritance. Having a member variable of type vector<int> would probably be a better choice.

Comment: @Andrea Bergia: It all depends on what you want to offer. While I have not used the private inheritance ever, I have seen it used when the derived class offered a subset of the container functionality with some extra operations. Aggregation there would require you to implement each operation as a forwarding call, while in the private inheritance case you can just *redeclare* them with using directives (`using base_t::push_back;` -- using a typdef for convenience)